# Sums of independent random variables cannot accumulate at a point

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Suppose that we have independent random variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots$, each of which has finite mean. I am interested in the condition

$$\underset{n\to\infty}{\lim} \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}} \mathbb{P}\Bigl(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i=x\Bigr)=0. \tag{A}$$

1. What are some necessary conditions which guarantee that condition $(A)$ holds?
2. What are some sufficient conditions which guarantee that condition $(A)$ holds?
3. What are some necessary conditions which guarantee that condition $(A)$ holds, under the additional hypothesis of identical distributions? My hope is that iid and non-constant would give $(A)$.
4. What are some sufficient conditions that guarantee that condition $(A)$ holds, under the additional hypothesis of identical distributions? The low hanging fruit here is the assumption of finite variance, since then CLT gives the conclusion. I'm hoping for something more general which could apply under the assumption of finite first moments, without necessarily assuming finite $1+\delta$ moments for any $\delta>0$.

Comment: You should be able to get to finite variance but I'm not sure, which is why this is a comment. If the random variables don't have atoms, (so a probability density function exists) the sum of the random variables has no atoms either, and the pdf of the sum of the $X_i$ is just the convolution of the densities, which is itself a density. It suffices to consider $X_i$ discretely valued. However, if the variance of $X_i$ is infinite, you must have that $X_i$ outputs infinitely many large values with positive probability. Perhaps there's a way to bound the pdf knowing this information.

Comment: I would have thought an approach is thinking of cases where it does not hold.  Having each $X_i$ constant would cause it to fail, as would having their distributions approach being a constant fast enough, such as with $\mathbb{P}\left(X_i=0\right)=2^{-2^{-n}}$ so your limit is at least $\frac12$.  I would have thought the answer to 3 and 4 is presumably the iid non-constant that you identified.  I do not see that having a finite mean helps

Comment: Having finite mean allows you to apply CLT to appropriate truncations of the random variables. The truncated part is well-behaved, so you only have to control the part above the truncation.